# Logistic regression: Confounding factor and Missing or not applicable data

Tags: logistic, missing-data, confounding

I am looking at confounding factors for relation 
'reporting type' (NR or SR) --> Completeness of a colorectal report (Yes (1) or No (0))

I have a possible confounding factor (CRM) that is only applicable for rectal cancer and not for colon cancer.

How do I test this confounding factor? It is a categorical factor, so CRM is free (1) or not free (0).

I usually use bivariable analysis to calculate the Mantel-Haenszel Odds Ratio to look for differences in the Odds Ratio compared to the crude Odds ratio.

So I would like to do look at the relation: 
complete report = constant + type of report*X + CRM*X2

Normally this would work, however CRM is only applicable in 30% of my cases (i.e. the rectal tumors). So if I adjust for CRM I will loose the colon cancer cases.

Do I re-code the colon cancer cases as not applicable or do I just leave them as being missing?
Or do I split my dataset in colon and rectum cases?

Or is there another option?

Comment: So to `test' anything, knowing more about how your data looks would be helpful. Could you visually show us your data structure, such as the unit of observation or at least some more info?

Comment: @frage_man I adjusted my question. Is it more clear like this? Or do you need more information?

Comment: It looks a lot better now. I don't know the answer, but I bet somebody does.